# Click and dblclick deliver different parentNodes on same html. Why?

Tags: javascript, click, selection, designmode

currently I work on an very small wysiwyg editor based on jquery. I dont care about IE oder Chrome, just Firefox. My problem is to find if the selection is in a link for to get the value of the href attribute if is set. With click the node of the link is found, with double click always the body.
It is in designMode.

My event-handler for click and dblclick.
The vars current_selection, current_node, iframe and container are global.

```
selection_handler:function()
{
  current_selection = iframe.getSelection();
  current_node = current_selection.anchorNode;
  if(current_node.nodeName == "#text")
  {
    current_node = current_node.parentNode;
  }
  $('#log').text(current_node.nodeName);
},
```

The log shows mit for example 'body', when I click in unformated text. When I add a link with execCommand('createLink',...) the log shows 'A'. That works. When I mark the linked word with 2 click from start to end, the log shows 'A'. But with double click I always get 'body'. So I can't get the href attribute.

The handler is defined in the init:

```
init:function(options)
{
  ...

  iframe = $('#wysiwyg-'+container.attr('id'))[0].contentWindow;
  iframe.addEventListener('dblclick',methods.selection_handler,false);
  iframe.addEventListener('click',methods.selection_handler,false);

  ...
}
```

Has somebody an idea what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Whe you dblclick on a link usually the complete link will be selected, the selection changes.

Use the event-object instead to determine which element has been clicked:

```
selection_handler:function(e)
{
  current_selection = window.getSelection();
  current_node = e.target;
  //...more code
}
```